# Web.config: invalid machineKey validationKey (non hex chars)?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

In my old MVC 4 website, I've used all type of letters (also non hex) in the "machineKey validationKey" in web.config - it worked fine.

But now I've upgraded the website to MVC 5 and it now fails with "invalid non hex values".

Can I tell MVC 5 to use all type of chars?

Why didn't my old site fail?

If I generate a new machineKey validationKey with hex values, I guess that all passwords will be invalid.

Any idea what to do?

Answer (score 1):

Found out that I could append compatibilityMode and it worked - like this...

```
<machineKey compatibilityMode="Framework20SP1" />
```

:)